# Trying to learn winapi. made a first program which has to show me a window. CMD shows but there is no window

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include<windows.h>

LPSTR NazwaKlasy = "Klasa Okienka";
MSG Komunikat;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;

wc.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
wc.style = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wc.hbrBackground =( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = NazwaKlasy;
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );

//tutaj kłądż okienka
HWND hwnd;
hwnd = CreateWindowEx ( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,NazwaKlasy,"Okienko",WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,400,400,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

//koniec obszaru okienek

ShowWindow( hwnd, nShowCmd ); // Pokaż okienko...
UpdateWindow( hwnd );

while( GetMessage( & Komunikat, NULL, 0, 0 ) )
{
 TranslateMessage( & Komunikat );
 DispatchMessage( & Komunikat );
}

return Komunikat.wParam;
}
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
switch( msg )
{
 case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow( hwnd );
     break;

 case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
     break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}

return 0;
}
```

the editor shows no errors and runs the program without any problems but there are no signs of the window 
im not very experienced at programming so its most probably a stupid error which i cant just find but everyone has to start somewhere
i think i formated the post correctly

Comment: Okienka, Okienko, Okienek? well you must be from Finland :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not registering the window class. You fill out the `WNDCLASSEX` structure ok, but you neglect to call `RegisterClassEx` to actually register it.

Comment: Thank you it worked. The site that im learning from merged it into the code that i though is just posted there so that the program will look funnier to the one that learns it so i didnt thought its important